# Are global constants of user defined types aligned?

Tags: c++, global

I have a user-defined type (class), `TMyClass`,  with a constructor that allows me to create constant instances of my class. If I evaluate `sizeof(TMyClass)` I get 28.

If I create a series of constants in a c++ source file

```
const TMyClass InstantA( /*.. constant initial values here.. */ );
const TMyClass InstantB( /*.. constant initial values here.. */ );
const TMyClass InstantC( /*.. constant initial values here.. */ );
```

I find that the GNU compiler has not put them next to each other in the memory space. If I try to iterate through them using a pointer (declared as `const TMYClass *MyPointer = &InstantA`) I find that when I move to the next one (using `MyPointer++;`) it doesn't point to `InstantB`.

Further, if I evaluate the addresses (`&InstantB`, `&InstantC`, etc) using the debugger, I find that they are more than 28 bytes apart.

I am surprised by this, I expected the globals of the same type to created "packed together" rather than at some alignment picked by the compiler.

If I put the series of constants into a constant array then they ARE packed as I expect.

QUESTION: What are the rules for when the compiler must pack global constants defined in sequence?

Comment: There is no rule.  In C++, unless you are using an array, you cannot iterate objects just by going to the next address.

Comment: alignment is unrelated to packing variable...

Comment: If you want objects stored contiguously and be able to use pointer arithmetic to access them, use an array or a vector.

Comment: unfortunately, your false premise aside there isnt much left of the question, because even if the answer would be yes, there isnt much you can do with that information

Comment: IMHO, packing only applies to elements in a struct or class.  Global variables will be allocated wherever the compiler deems appropriate (or wherever the linker decides to place them).

Comment: Now if they were in a `struct` and we "know" there is no padding ... maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Consider what the standard specifies, not what will happen on some specific hardware. Then memory adresses of different objects have no relation. Comparing them via `<` has unspecified result. You may only increment a pointer to an object once and you cannot dereference the resulting pointer. Dereferecing it or incrementing it further invokes undefined behavior.

Pointer arithmetics is only allowed with pointers to elements of arrays.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the compiler is adhering to the standard : "memory addresses of different objects have no relation". Can you confirm if this also applies to objects declared in a class or struct (as opposed to an array). eg class TMyTypes {const TMyClass InstantA( /*.. constant initial values here.. */ );
const TMyClass InstantB( /*.. constant initial values here.. */ );
const TMyClass InstantC( /*.. constant initial values here.. */ );};

Comment: @RogerCigol I don't know this by heart, I would have to browse the standard. I remember that something changed recently with respect to the order in which members are layed out in memory, but I believe you still cannot compare their adresses reliably (i might be wrong though)